# iPhone app supports Retina only. Will Apple accept the app?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I just ported an iPad app to the iPhone and due to graphical and programming reasons it doesn't work on the low res displays (3G and 3GS).  The starts on the low res devices but the graphics are garbled.

Is it possible to submit the app like that if the description specifically states that it is for iPhone 4 and iPod Touch 4g only?

Comment: Out of curiosity: What reasons?

Comment: Coordinates.  It is very simple to port a graphical app from iPad to iPhone4 because the displays are of similar size.  Porting to the low res displays is more difficult (as everything has to be scaled).  I'd rather spend that time on other apps.

Comment: Asking "Will Apple accept the app?" is pointless, since none of us here can vouch for Apple.

Comment: I wasn't asking for a guaranteed agreement sealed by Jobs' private secretary but the opinion of fellow developers who might be for example had their app rejected for that same reason.

Comment: Out of curiosity, was your app accepted after using 'UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities' even though your app doesn't make use of the front facing camera?

Comment: Yes.  At least at the time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While you cannot limit by model, you can require certain hardware device capabilities for your app. These are specified in the plist file for the app using the "UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities" key.

For example, if you say your app requires a front-facing camera, that would limit it to those devices that have that, eliminating the 3G and 3GS.

Comment: Thank you. I'll use the front facing camera requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the supported devices (`UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities`) are specified appropriates in your Info.plist file. That done, the app will not be rejected on these grounds.

Comment: Unfortunately Retina is not a requirement that can be set.

Comment: @user: You can cheat and require a camera. This was only available on the iPhone/iPod Touch 4 and later.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. You will need to limit it bt hardware. For example the iPhone 4 is the ONLY phone with the front facing camera. So you'd need to enable that.

Look in the Info.plist and UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities

UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities

```
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<array>
 <string>telephony</string>
 <string>gps</string>
  <string>location-services</string>
</array>
```

Will prevent it from running on iPad (no telephony and possibly no gps) and iPod Touch because of the same reasons.

You will also need to add the restriction for the front facing camera to prevent it from older iPhone hardware

Answer (score 0):

They should.  Just clearly document the requirement.  There are other hardware differences that applications make use of, so this isn't a problem that is limited to the retina display.

For example, an application that was centered around taking video would be limited in what hardware it would work with as well.

Answer (score 0):

Retina display has 4 times more pixels than regular iPhone, but screen size remains the same. So if you naively port iPad application on iPhone it won't be usable because all elements will be **much** smaller than on iPad. Retina can only make them sharper, but not bigger. Don't get fooled by iPhone Simulator. Retina mode on it with 100% scale on Mac screen is no way comparable to the real thing.

Comment: I've developed and published multiple iPad and iPhone apps so I'm aware of the discrepancy between the simulator and the actual device.  The actual problem is that coordinates have to be changed when moving from the iPad to the low res iPhone.  When porting to the iPhone coordinates can be kept the same if you avoid placing images near the border.  Thanks to the Retina resolution the graphics don't have to be rescaled or redrawn as the screen is crisp enough.